# "xtime: ambiguous symbol" error, when including <boost/asio.hpp>

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

As said in the title, when I'm trying to include asio.hpp from boost I get this error:

```
'xtime': ambiguous symbol (compiling source file FILEPATH)
note: could be 'xtime'    (compiling source file FILEPATH)
or   'boost::xtime'       (compiling source file FILEPATH)
```

I have read that this issue can be linked with *"using namespace"* but after removing all this statements in my project error still pops up. Do you have any idea what else than *"using namespace"* can cause this problem?

Comment: Please extract a [mcve], along with the exact command issued to compile the code. Also, provide the exact versions of related tools and software. BTW: Check the Boost bug tracking system as well, you might have discovered a bug.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt sadly giving exact example is very hard in my case, because I keep getting this error in huge commercial application. I'm aware that sources which I linked are a little poor so probably I will have to handle it myself. Thanks for your answer anyway.

Comment: FILEPATH is going to be key information. If it's a boost header, you might reorder the conflicting include after the boost include OR file a bug that you run into this problem. If it's your own code, (a) stop using `using namespace` and/or (b) qualify your use of `xtime`.

Comment: @sehe Your answer actually resolved my problem. FILEPATH was one of my own files but I tried to reorder includes in it anyway and it worked! much thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [sehe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/85371/sehe) mentioned in comments, reordering include statements in FILEPATH have resolved the problem.